# How to Implement Drag and drop of components using richfaces with background ruler/graph to get the exact co-ordinates

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, richfaces, jsf-1.2

How to Implement Drag and drop of components using richfaces with background ruler/graph to get the exact co-ordinates.

Have used the following code to add(drag/drop) components to a panel

```
<h:panelGrid columns="4" styleClass="main-tab-panel" style="width:1000px;height: 300px ">
<!-- Draggable components which can be dragged and dropped in Drop zones -->
<rich:simpleTogglePanel switchType="client" style="height:500px" bodyClass="rich-laguna-panel-no-header">
<rich:tabPanel  selectedTab="createForm"  style="background-color:#{richSkin.tabBackgroundColor};width:110px;">
    <rich:tab id="createForm" >
      <f:facet name="label"><h:outputText value="Add Fields"/></f:facet>

         <rich:dataGrid id="srcTable"  columns="1" value="#{dragDropService.sourceComponents}" var="_srcComponent">
         <rich:column styleClass="fdAddButton">
            <a:outputPanel style="width:128px;"
                           onmouseover="this.style.cursor='move'" layout="block">
                <rich:dragSupport dragIndicator="indicator"
                                  dragType="DRAG_COMPONENT" dragValue="#{_srcComponent}">
                   <rich:dndParam id="test" name="label" value="#{_srcComponent.displayName}"  />
                </rich:dragSupport>
              <h:outputText value="#{_srcComponent.fieldName}" styleClass="fdAddButton" onmouseover="this.className='fdAddButton-act'"  onmouseout="this.className='fdAddButton'"></h:outputText>
            </a:outputPanel>
         </rich:column>
    </rich:dataGrid>
  </rich:tab>
  </rich:tabPanel>
 </rich:simpleTogglePanel>
```

```
<rich:panel id="ctrlPanel"  style="width:1000px;height:500px;">
      <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="Drop Zone "/></f:facet>
    <rich:separator></rich:separator>
     <rich:dropSupport acceptedTypes="DRAG_COMPONENT" dropValue="" dropListener="#{dragDropService.processDrop}" reRender="dropTable,srcTable">
     </rich:dropSupport>
     <h:panelGroup id="dropTable" binding="#{dragDropService.panelGroup}">
        </h:panelGroup>
```

I am trying to get the co-ordinates using the below code:

```
//<![CDATA[
function getOffset(){
    //parent - panel Grid
    var parent = document.getElementById('contentForm:dropTable');
    parentObject=parent.getBoundingClientRect();
    var parentTop=parentObject.top;
    var parentLeft=parentObject.left;

    var positions = new Array();
    var delimitedValues;

    var child = parent.getElementsByTagName('table');
    var name = parent.getElementsByTagName('label');


    for(i = 0 ; i <= child.length - 1; i++){

        var component = child.item(i);
        rectObject = component.getBoundingClientRect();

        var childTop=rectObject.top-parentTop;
        var childLeft=rectObject.left-parentLeft;
        var field = name.item(i).innerHTML;
        positions.push([childTop,childLeft,field]);
        delimitedValues = positions.join("|");

        alert(delimitedValues+"   delimitedValues");

    }


    document.getElementById('contentForm:childOffset').value = delimitedValues;

}

//]]>
```

The components are overlapping when we drag and drop.
Components are not positioned side by side i.e. in multiple columns though I drag new component beside existing component.
How to achieve these criteria.

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do? It's not really clear. You are dragging an element and when you drop it you want to know the position of the mouse?

Comment: First of all I need to get the position of component thats been dragged not mouse position. I m able to get this using javascript snippet that i have added above. But the problem is that I m unable to place the component anywhere in the screen. Currently wherever I drag the components, they are being placed vertically i.e. 1 below the other.

Comment: So you want to drag the component and when you drop it you want it to stay on the spot it was dropped?

Comment: Exactly, it has to be positioned wherever its dropped

Comment: Ah, ok. I think you misunderstand how it works. What you're dragging is a clone of the component, the actual component is transferred server-side. If you only need to move DOM elements you are better off using just JavaScript, like the `draggable` widget from jQuery.

Comment: But the requirement from the client is that the components have to be placed wherever dragged and positions saved to DB. When user logs in next time, the components' positions have to be retrieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drag'n'drop functionality of RichFaces isn't really designed for what you're trying to do but something like this might work:

`<a4j:jsFunction>` can be used to send data from JavaScript to your bean

```
<a4j:jsFunction name="setPosition">
    <a4j:actionparam assignTo="#{bean.id}" name="id"/>
    <a4j:actionparam assignTo="#{bean.top}" name="top"/>
    <a4j:actionparam assignTo="#{bean.left}" name="left"/>
</a4j:jsFunction>
```

and then you need to make your component draggable and call the jsFunction when you stop dragging; RF 3 uses [draggable from sript.aculo.us](http://madrobby.github.io/scriptaculous/draggable/):

```
new Draggable('componentId', { onEnd : function (obj, event) {
    setPosition( obj.element.id , event.y , event.x );
});
```

the event is standard mouseevent, so you may need a different set of coordinates, and of course you should probably use just one parameter and then parse it in the bean, you cannot directly call a bean method and use the params as arguments.